# CR1220 holder 2D footprint error from manufacturer?

Tags: batteries

I just ordered a PCB that uses a certain battery holder. I am looking at the 2D footprint and 3d model now thinking there must be some error, but I wanted to confirm this before I recall the PCB, also I don't spot too many errors these days so I am skeptical of myself.

Looking at the schematics, pad 1 & 2 are specified to be + and - respectively.  If we take a look at the 3d model in the STEP file and 3d pictures on the datasheet how is it possible that 1 and 2 are isolated?  The frame is metal and these two pads are connected... Is MP1 meant to be the negative? [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/215/Keystone_Electronics_04082019_2894-1551346.pdf)

[image: footprint]

[image: 3d pic 2]

[image: 3d pic 1]

Comment: Where did you get the symbol and footprint? I've found numerous errors with them when obtaining from manufacturer or a source like Ultra Librarian, GrabCad, etc.

Comment: Mouser is where I got it, my experience with them has been good

Comment: The 3D file also doesnt match the datasheet. 3D seems through hole, datasheet and land patterns seem to be for SMD.

Comment: I think you are right here, Keystone coin cell receiver# 2895 is THT and 2894 is SMD but they both have this labeling issue on Mouser.  @WesleyLee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is a "coin cell retainer" not a "coin cell holder". The difference:

- [coin cell retainer](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=device_sockets&u=battery_clips_holders&o=coin_cell_clips_holders&f=pcb_coin_cell_retainers)*: contacts only the top if the cell; non-isolated; the PCB contacts the bottom
- [coin cell holder](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=device_sockets&u=battery_clips_holders&o=coin_cell_clips_holders&f=pcb_coin_cell_holders)*: contacts both terminals of the cell; isolated

You need to make a PCB layout symbol for your part that includes two outer pads for the retainer plus a center pad for the PCB contact to the cell.

Reference also [this question in stack exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/226967/coin-cell-battery-retainer-problems-and-best-practices)

*My site

Comment: I see now the difference between these two terms!  But why would the 2d footprint label 1 and 2 as + and - when 1 and 2 are both positive and the center plane is negative?  Also the reference is great

Comment: A good question, whatever the answer is, the footprint doesn’t match the schematic part.  1and 2 are indeed both positive.